# Add to favourites issue using fragments and gridview android

Tags: android, listview, gridview, fragment, favorites

so i have a `ViewPager` and a `Save to Favorite` button on my `HomeFragment`. when i click on the button i want the images to be stored and then retrieved on another fragment, for which im using`FavGridAdapter`. I tried using getter/setter for the position but it doesnt work. Following are the codes for `HomeFragment` , `FavGridAdapter` and `FavList`(getter/setter).

`HomeFragment`

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private static int currentPage;
ViewPager viewPager;

public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
    return new HomeFragment();
}

public HomeFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
            false);

    /*
     * ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonEnq);
     * ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     * 
     * @Override public void onClick(View v) { InfoFragment infoFragment =
     * new InfoFragment(); //FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
     * //fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,
     * infoFragment).commit();
     * 
     * FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     * //ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom, 0);
     * ft.addToBackStack(null);
     * ft.replace(R.id.frame_container,infoFragment); ft.commit(); } });
     */

    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
    ImageAdapter adapter1 = new ImageAdapter(this.getActivity());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter1);

    Button buttonFav = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonFav);
    buttonFav.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

            //List<FavList> fav = new ArrayList<FavList>();
            FavList item=new FavList();
            item.setPosition(position);
            Log.e("error", "item:" +item);
            //fav.add(item);

            /*CommunityFragment fragment  = new CommunityFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putLong("position", position);
            Log.e("error", "bundle:"+bundle.toString());
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);*/
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    try {

        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class
                .getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

`FavGridAdapter`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class FavGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
int position1;

public FavGridAdapter(Context c,int position) {
    context = c;
    this.position1=position;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return GalImages.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    FavList item = new FavList();
    int i = item.getPosition();

    Log.e("error", "getpos:"+i);
    imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[i]);
    return imageView;
}

private int[] GalImages = new int[] { R.drawable.gw12, R.drawable.gw1,
        R.drawable.gw2, R.drawable.gw3, R.drawable.gw4, R.drawable.gw5,
        R.drawable.gw6, R.drawable.gw7, R.drawable.gw8, R.drawable.gw9,
        R.drawable.gw11, R.drawable.gw81 };
}
```

`FavList`

```
public class FavList {

int position;

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}

public FavList() {
};



}
```

is this the right way to do it ??? if another techniques please do let me know. THANK YOU.

Comment: You're creating a new FavList every time you're using it, so it's not going to be able to "store" anything the way you want it because they're different objects. Also, your getItem call in FavGridAdapter is returns null always. As an aside, you can use Log.d(String tag, String message) for debugging, which leaves Log.e for errors.

Comment: So your intended functionality is: You open up Home Fragment and it has a view pager, you 'favorite' a few of the images, you leave the fragment, you go to some other fragment and it shows your 'favorited' images? Have I got that right?

Comment: @user2152081 yess you have got it right... can you plzz help me with this. i researched a lot on the internet but couldnt find a proper answer..

Comment: thank you guys for your efforts but i solved it using database.. putting each position in a database and then retrieving in another fragment.. but the issue is i can do that only for one fragment.. can anyone help me for other fragments ??

Comment: Can you update your code to what you're using now?